# are these two lines of code equivalent?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check existence of directory and create if doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216753/check-existence-of-directory-and-create-if-doesnt-exist)

Is this line of code

```
if(!file.exists("PLOTS")) dir.create("PLOTS")
```

equivalent to this line of code?

```
dir.create('PLOTS',showWarnings=FALSE)
```

Is there any circumstance in which one will work and the other will not?

Comment: What is the programming language you are using??

Comment: @SunilKumarBM The OP correctly tagged the question as [tag:r], meaning he is using R.  See the tag info for more information.

Comment: I updated the title just to make things clearer.

Comment: your first line works in Windows too.

Comment: cool, thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: also, the second one works just fine in Windows with no side effects. If the folder already exists and has stuff in it, then nothing is done, otherwise one is created.

Comment: good find Chase! I did not find that in my search. However, I am still interested in if these two lines of code are equivalent. Thus, I think my question is different. I will edit my question to clarify that.

Comment: The two are broadly equivalent. However there exist cases where the `dir.create("PLOTS")` command will fail in the first line and show a warning but the second command will hide any information from the user and still fail. An example would be if a file exists with the same name or if the folder is not writable. See my answer to the possible duplicate for a more robust solution.