# R files run incompletely but without error on Windows server

Tags: r, windows, server, rscript

I have a series of R files on my desktop computer that run daily when triggered by Windows Task Manager. I'm trying to migrate these files over to a server so that they're not dependent on my local machine, but I'm having trouble.

The server a Windows 2012 R2 Server and I have full admin permissions. R.exe and Rscript.exe are both installed on the server. However, when I try to run the files, they do run only incompletely. For example, my test case is a hello world file that prints "hello world" to the console screen and then writes the phrase to a CSV. Rscript will open the file and print "hello world" on the console, but will not create the CSV. I don't see any error displayed.

What's going on?

Comment: It's probably creating the file in a default location. use `setwd()`

Comment: @HubertL Please do **not** use `setwd` inside R (and please don’t suggest this), [it leads to mayhem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13770896/1968). Use properly specified file paths instead.

Comment: OK thanks for the tip @KonradRudolph