# loading downloaded data to Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

mission on online course:

Download this *RData file* to your working directory. Then load the data into R with the following command:

load("skew.RData")

so I have downloaded it to my computer but where is my working directory? or how do I load the downloaded file to Rstudio

Comment: Your working directory is the directory that your code is running in. If you’re using projects in RStudio, it’s the project directory. If you’re not using projects … you should start using projects. But you can find out the working directory via `getwd()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can see your working directory by executing `getwd()`.
In order to load the data you need to change it to the folder path where the data is stored.

```
setwd("C:/your/path")
load("skew.RData")
```

Comment: You almost certainly *do not* want to use `setwd`, or hard-code paths.

Comment: Do you mean that using `setwd()` is bad practice as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770304/risks-of-using-setwd-in-a-script) or are there any other risks in using `setwd()` in combination with `load()`?

Comment: It’s for these reasons, but Ben Bolkers is too lenient, and pretends that using `setwd` is less bad than it actually is. Here’s a more honest take: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/

Answer (score 0):

You can set you working directory in RStudio on the right side manually and then save the files there and open them like :

```
load("skew.RData")
```

If your file is saved somewhere else, you should define the path to it:

```
load("path/to/your/file/skew.RData")
```