# Set working directory to file location in R

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudioapi

I have a folder, say **program**, which contains all my scripts, data, etc:

- main.R
- src/

  - other_file_1.R
  - other_file_2.R
- data/

  - some_dataset.csv
  - output/

    - stuff.txt
    - other_stuff.png
- logs/
- Readme.txt

The person who receives my folder, opens it and runs *main.R*.

Now, since I wanna be able to read and write in the subfolders shown above, I want to set the working directory to the **program** folder from the *main.R* script.

So I do this:

```
install.packages("rstudioapi")
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error in getActiveDocumentContext() : 
could not find function "getActiveDocumentContext"
```

I've also tried loading the library:

```
library(rstudioapi)
setwd(dirname(getActiveDocumentContext()$path))
```

but I get the same error.

Comment: Changing the working directory is generally considered to be [poor practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73489216/choose-working-directory-in-code-option-of-r-chunk#73489216).  Better to (determine the actual working directory and then) construct relative paths to the desired resources.

Comment: Are you actually running the code in the RStudio IDE? The "could not find function" error does not seem like the one you should be getting if you actually called `rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()`. Are you sure that's the code you are running? What verison of R are you running? But I would second the fact that you should not programmatically set the working directory. Better to use something like an RStudio project or there [here](https://here.r-lib.org/) package to deal with relative paths.