# Use apply functions dir.exist and dir.create

Tags: r

I am trying to use a vector of characters to create a series of directories in my working directory.  Nothing recursive, simply iterative.  Nothing fancy.  as an example, I can do this pretty easily with:

```
lapply(state.name, dir.create)
```

which creates 50 directories of all US states in my working directory.  I can easily delete them if I want using:

```
unlink(state.name)
```

However, what I would really like to do is test to see if any of the directories exist already, and then create the ones that are not already there.  I have found similar questions here: [Check existence of directory and create if doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216753/check-existence-of-directory-and-create-if-doesnt-exist) but everything I have found on Stack Exchange and through other Google searches either take a deep dive into the apply family of functions, or explain how to create a single directory in R.  The recursive checking and creating I would like to do does not seem to exist.  I have come up with the following, and it works, sort of, but it is really only checking the first entry in the vector.

```
if(!file.exists(state.name)) {lapply(state.name, dir.create)}
```

If I try to use the lapply function with file.exists, it throws an error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
lapply(state.name, function(x) if(!dir.exists(x)) dir.create(x))
```

Comment: Thanks!  That is what I was looking for.  I new it was something simple I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

```
lapply(state.name[!state.name %in% dir()], dir.create)
```