# Create subdirectories inside a directory at once in R

Tags: r, function, directory, subdirectory

I've been looking in SO for a thread about how to create two (or n) subdirectories in a directory at once in R and only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216753/check-existence-of-directory-and-create-if-doesnt-exist) which it's not quiete what I want.

I can do it in two lines by doing:

```
dir.create(file.path(getwd(), "test"))

sapply(letters[1:2], 
   function(x) dir.create(file.path(getwd(), "test", paste0(x, "_test"))))

#   a    b 
#TRUE TRUE
```

How can I do it in one line?

Thank you.

Comment: what do yo mean by one line? what's wrong with your approach?

Comment: With "one line" I meant at once, without do the first `dir.create`

Comment: so you want to create sub directory without creating the parent directory?

Comment: Sorry, maybe my comment is ambiguous. I want to crate a directory `test` and then create inside it two subdirectory `a_test` and `b_test`. But I'd rather do it at once, instead of do it in two steps.

Answer (score 7):

dir.create(file.path(getwd(), 'test'), recursive = TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

```
new_folder_path<-paste(getwd(),"new_folder",sep = "/")      
create_sub_folders<-function(x){
      dir.create(x)
      setwd(x)
      ifelse(dir.exists(x)!=TRUE,print("dir already exists"),dir.create(paste(x,"test_a",sep = "/")))
      ifelse(dir.exists(x)!=TRUE,print("dir already exists"),dir.create(paste(x,"test_b",sep = "/")))}
```

not sure if this is what you want.
create the `new_folder_path` you want then just type this into the `create_sub_folders` function and it will create the subfolders you want..(sorry not in one line!)