# How make a function to cycle through working directories

Tags: r

I use my flash drive to store all my R `csv` files but I write them from my desktop, laptop, and work computer. Is there a way to build a function that will ignore `setwd` if that drive is not present?

```
Working_D_Noah.H1N1 <- function(){

 #my work space miller lab computer
 if(setwd("E:/Miller Lab/Noah.H1N1/CSV Files")) return ("E:/Miller Lab/Noah.H1N1/CSV Files")

 #my desktop
 else(setwd("I:/Miller Lab/Noah.H1N1/CSV Files")) return("I:/Miller Lab/Noah.H1N1/CSV Files")

          #my lap top
          (setwd("F:/Miller Lab/Noah.H1N1/CSV Files")) return("F:/Miller Lab/Noah.H1N1/CSV Files")
                }
Working_D_Noah.H1N1
```

As an example, I expect that if I am on my desktop and run this code, that R will select one working directory that is available.

Comment: You can [check that the directory exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216753/check-existence-of-directory-and-create-if-doesnt-exist) before using `setwd()`. Do you use R studio? Because RStudio projects will set the working directory relative to the project file so you don't have to bother with the `setwd()` yourself and it makes things much nicer.

Comment: `if(dir.exists("I:/etc"))`

Comment: Yes! that worked MDEWITT, you made my morning.