# ggsave() fails with Error in png_dev(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : unable to start png() device

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggsave

When I try to save a ggplot to a new directory with `ggsave()`, I get an error.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl)) +
  geom_bar()
ggsave("current_folder/new_folder/new_plot.png")
```

Produces the error:

```
Saving 11.3 x 7.32 in image
Error in png_dev(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : 
  unable to start png() device
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In png_dev(..., res = dpi, units = "in") :
  unable to open file 'current_folder/new_folder/new_plot.png' for writing
2: In png_dev(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : opening device failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the target directory does not already exist, `ggsave()` will not create it as part of saving.  It will instead throw this error.

First create the directory, either in your operating system outside of R or with `dir.create` like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29784923.

Then save with `ggsave()`.